# SSRS Report Table Add Column Expression Record x of y?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012, record, ssrs-tablix, rowcount

I have an SSRS, which is compiled of report tables, each tied to a stored procedure, all keying off the same ID.  I pass the ID automatically, through the UI.

Because there is so much information in the report, For each section, I wanted to add a column to each table, with an expression. It would give the record count. This would mean, that if the table had an artist's albums, there would be a column for Album Record, and it would be something like this:

Arist: Pink
Album Record   Album Name   Album Release Date   Etc
1 of 5
2 of 5
3 of 5

To build the pieces of the Album record, I added a row counter to the stored procedure.  This is that SQL line:

```
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pc.ID ORDER BY ARID.ID) 'Album Record Number'
```

pc.id is the ID parameter that is passed, which means, we only pass and retrieve 1 pc.ID.  The ARID.ID is for the sub-record ID's.

This creates the first piece.  Record 1,2,3.

In the SSRS table, I add a column and I make an expression:

```
=Fields!Album_Record_Number.Value & " of " & Count(Fields!ARID.Value,"ID")
```

This should give me "1 of 3", "2 of 3", "3 of 3".

When I attempt to preview the report, I get an error:

> An error occurred during local report processing. The definition of
>   the report '/MainReport' is invalid. The Value expression for the text
>   box 'XYZ' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate
>   function. The scope parameter must be set to a string that is equal to
>   either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data
>   region or the name of a dataset.

Anyone know how to do what I'm trying to do? I'm dreading that I may have to add the total count to the stored procedure, which means I would have to add that to all my stored procs.  I was hoping an expression in a table column would do the trick.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you already using [`Groups`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) so you can use a similar expression:

```
=RowNumber("YourAlbumGrouping") & " of " & CountRows("YourAlbumGrouping")
```

[`RowNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-rownumber-function?view=sql-server-2017) function returns a running count of the number of rows for the specified scope.

[`CountRows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-countrows-function?view=sql-server-2017) function returns the number of rows in the specified scope, including rows with null values.

Comment: I've never done that before. What is the "YourAlbumGrouping" ? Where do I get that object/name from?

Comment: answer updated with links to MSDN; give a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I had to group by the main ID that I am passing. That is the trick to get that formula to work. It works!!! So elegant and simple! You just saved me so much time!